# Generated Razor view file does not recognise the model class

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-mvc

As I build and run (`dotnet run`) my ASP.NET Core MVC project using VS Code, I get the following two error messages:

> obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Razor/Views/Product/List.g.cshtml.cs(28,88):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ProductsListViewModel' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?) [/Users/pedram/OneDrive - House of Friends
>   AB/visualstudioonmacprojects/SportsStore/SportsStore.csproj]
>
> obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Razor/Views/Product/List.g.cshtml.cs(128,71):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ProductsListViewModel' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?) [/Users/pedram/OneDrive - House of Friends
>   AB/visualstudioonmacprojects/SportsStore/SportsStore.csproj]
>
> The build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.

When I navigate to the files mentioned I realize that the class `ProductsListViewModel` needs to be addressed using its full name `SportsStore.Models.ViewModels.ProductsListViewModel` in both places for the project to build correctly. But this only resolves the problem until the next build.

Cleaning the project before building (`dotnet clean`) does not seem to help either.

I do not have much control over things happening inside the **obj** folder. What is causing this missing namespace problem?

**Update:**

The contents of `/Views/Product/List.cshtml`

```
@model ProductsListViewModel
@foreach (var p in Model.Products) {
    @Html.Partial("ProductSummary", p)
}
<div page-model="@Model.PagingInfo" page-action="List" page-classes-enabled="true"
     page-class="btn" page-class-normal="btn-secondary"
     page-class-selected="btn-primary" class="btn-group pull-right m-1">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know about VS Code, but VS will compile, but if you look under Errors List, it will show that class is missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first line of your .cshtml file, you declare the type of the model that is being used in your view. From the error message, it's clear that `ProductsListViewModel` cannot be resolved. To solve that issue, you have at least two options:

1. Use `@model SportsStore.Models.ViewModels.ProductsListViewModel`, which is a fully-qualified name (FQN).
2. Use `@using`, like this:

   ```
   @using SportsStore.Models.ViewModels
   @model ProductsListViewModel
   ```

It's *mostly* a matter of preference as to which you should choose.

Visual Studio Code doesn't seem to support Razor files as well as Visual Studio - It seems to have decent syntax-highlighting support, but doesn't seem to compile the .cshtml files in order to discover compilation errors like the one you're having.

The file you first modified (`List.g.cshtml.cs`) is a *generated* file, that is produced from processing your .cshtml file and should not be modified. If you do modify it, it gets replaced next time the source .cshtml file is processed.

Comment: this solution is also valid for JetBrains Rider (2020.2.1).  
Seems Rider suffers from the same limitations